# Python PANDAS: Drop All Rows After First Occurrence of Column Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a PANDAS dataframe with a columns with an open/closed status value and a ranking field value.  After I sort by the rank field, what would be the best way to drop/delete all rows after the first occurrence of an "open" value? I'm just confused if I should take an iterator function or standard index based approach with PANDAS.  Any advice would be great!

Edit: This is just what I have started with thus far

```
df["Rank", "Status"].sort_values(by="Rank")
```

The output I am trying to accomplish would look like the following:

From this:

```
Rank Status
1    Closed
5    Closed
6    Open
9    Closed
10   Open
```

To this:

```
Rank Status
 1    Closed
 5    Closed
 6    Open
```

Comment: Complement for this problem : If the selection has to be done for multiple Shops in the same dataframe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70291052/drop-all-rows-after-first-occurrence-of-column-value/70291156?noredirect=1#comment124255294_70291156

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply reindex the data frame when you sort it and then find the index location of the first instance of 'Open' and slice the data to there....

```
import pandas as pd
#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Rank' : [5, 1, 10 ,6, 9],   
'Status' : ['Closed', 'Closed', 'Open', 'Closed', 'Open']
})

# sort and reindex
df = df.sort('Rank').reset_index()

#slice to first occurrence of your value
df.loc[: df[(df['Status'] == 'Open')].index[0], :]
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost the same answer. Manipulating df directly.

```
df = df[:df[df['Status'] == 'Open'].index[0]]
```

This will return the index of the first instance of the value and then slice the DataFrame up to that row.

Comment: This solution (imo) does not include the row with the first occurence of `open` (as requested by the OP). Therefore I think it should be `df[:df[df['Status'] == 'Open'].index[0]+1]`