# Drop All Rows After First Occurrence of Column Value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My problem is the same as this one, with an additional constraint I can't figure how to solve :

[Python PANDAS: Drop All Rows After First Occurrence of Column Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163431/python-pandas-drop-all-rows-after-first-occurrence-of-column-value)

In this post, the issue is to remove all lines once Open occurred for the 1st time :

Start :

```
Rank Status
1    Closed
5    Closed
6    Open
9    Closed
10   Open
```

Result :

```
Rank Status
 1    Closed
 5    Closed
 6    Open
```

Here's the best answer to the problem :

```
df = df.sort('Rank').reset_index()
df.loc[: df[(df['Status'] == 'Open')].index[0], :]
```

I have the same problem, but I have multiple Shops in the same dataframe, and want it computed for all of them :

Start :

```
Shop Rank  Status
A    1     Closed
A    5     Closed
A    6     Open
A    9     Closed
A    10    Open
A    1     Closed
B    3     Closed
B    8     Closed
B    12    Open
B    15    Closed
...
```

The result I want :

```
Shop Rank  Status
A    1     Closed
A    5     Closed
A    6     Open
B    3     Closed
B    8     Closed
B    12    Open
...
```

How shall I modify the past answer to adapt it to all my Shops at the same time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is processing column per groups by compare `Open` and [`Series.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html), because need also first `Open` is necessary shift:

```
mask = (df['Status'].eq('Open')
                    .groupby(df['Shop'])
                    .transform(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=False).cummax()))

df = df[~mask]
print (df)
  Shop  Rank  Status
0    A     1  Closed
1    A     5  Closed
2    A     6    Open
6    B     3  Closed
7    B     8  Closed
8    B    12    Open
```

If always `Open` per groups is possible use:

```
def f(x):
    
    return x.loc[: x[(x['Status'] == 'Open')].index[0], :]

df = df.groupby('Shop', group_keys=False).apply(f)
```

---

```
def f(x):
    
    return x.loc[: (x['Status'] == 'Open').idxmax()]

df = df.groupby('Shop', group_keys=False).apply(f)
```

EDIT:

Test with general data:

```
print (df)
   Shop  Rank  Status
0     A     1  Closed
1     A     5  Closed
2     A     6    Open
3     A     9  Closed
4     A    10    Open
5     A     1  Closed
6     B     3  Closed
7     B     8  Closed
8     B    12    Open
9     B    15  Closed
10    C     8  Closed <- in C group no Open
11    C    12  Closed
12    D    15    Open <- in D group first Open
13    D    15  Closed
```

This solution failed, because no `Open` in `C` group:

```
def f(x):
    
    return x.loc[: x[(x['Status'] == 'Open')].index[0], :]

df = df.groupby('Shop', group_keys=False).apply(f)
```

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

---

```
def f(x):
    
    return x.loc[: (x['Status'] == 'Open').idxmax()]

df = df.groupby('Shop', group_keys=False).apply(f)

print (df)
   Shop  Rank  Status
0     A     1  Closed
1     A     5  Closed
2     A     6    Open
6     B     3  Closed
7     B     8  Closed
8     B    12    Open
10    C     8  Closed <- incorrect return first False row
12    D    15    Open
```

First solution working well:

```
mask = (df['Status'].eq('Open')
                    .groupby(df['Shop'])
                    .transform(lambda x: x.shift(fill_value=False).cummax()))

df1 = df[~mask]
print (df1)
   Shop  Rank  Status
0     A     1  Closed
1     A     5  Closed
2     A     6    Open
6     B     3  Closed
7     B     8  Closed
8     B    12    Open
10    C     8  Closed
11    C    12  Closed
12    D    15    Open
```

Comment: It worked perfectly for me, thanks a lot. However, I don't understand what you mean with "If always Open per groups is possible"

Comment: @Adept - Sure, give me some time, adding to answer.

Comment: I got it. I'm in the case it's possible not having any Open in a group, and the 1st solution worked well.

Comment: @Adept - One question -if no `Open` need remove group `C` or not?

Comment: No, I want to keep all rows of C, which is done correctly in your first solution