# How to search for first instance of string in pandas dataframe and remove all rows after it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a CSV that I've read into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('printers.csv')
```

How can I find the first occurrence of the string "**locally mapped**" from the `df["Print Server"]` column, and then remove all *rows* after and including that one?

Thanks

Comment: As well as Duplicate also see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163431/python-pandas-drop-all-rows-after-first-occurrence-of-column-value)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.head(df['Print Server'].ne('locally mapped').idxmin())
```

Comment: That won't work unless the index is a RangeIndex, better use the approach in the duplicate